# Вычислить произведение сумм для заданного числа n:

Tags: c++, алгоритм

[image: Задача]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    int n = 0;
    float sum = 0, mult = 1;
    cout << "Введите n(n >= 0): ";
    cin >> n;
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            sum += ((float)i / (float)j);
        }
    mult *= sum;
    sum = 0;
    }
    cout << "Произведение:" << mult << endl;
}
```

> У препода получается 3024 при 3, у меня 36. Кто прав? Как вы понимаете эту задачу?

Comment: С точки зрения математики :) это 36.

Comment: я тоже так думаю

Comment: Покажите ему это: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5BSum%5Bi%2Fj%2C+%7Bi%2C+1%2C+n%7D%5D%2C+%7Bj%2C+1%2C+n%7D%5D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще-то математически это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и равно при `n==3` ровно 36...

Как препод мог получить 3024 — не понимаю.